# MPI parallel programming of the sieve of eratosthenes. Internal loop only

Tags: c++, loops, parallel-processing, mpi, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying to parallelize with the mpi library and c++ the internal loop of the following sequential code (sieve of eratosthenes):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int64_t n = 40;
    int64_t root = std::sqrt(n);
    int count = 0;

    bool* range = new bool[n];
    for (int64_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        range[i] = true;
    }
    
    for (int64_t i = 2; i <= root; i++)
    {
        if (range[i])
        {
            //Loop to be parallelized
            for (int64_t j = i * i; j < n; j += i)
            {
                range[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (int64_t k = 2; k < n; k++)
    {
        if (range[k])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("Primes: %d", count);
}
```

**I don't want to parallelize the external loop**, which although it would be a better solution, I must compare both performances.

In other words, I would like to parallel the distribution of the elimination of multiples, which occurs when range[j] takes the value of false

Thank you in advance.